# HTML input file прикрепление к другим полям

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

Здравствуйте всем!

Интересует такое решение задачки. Имеется вот такой вот HTML код

```
        <input type="text" name="comp" placeholder="Comp" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name1" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[]" placeholder="desc1" /><br>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>

        <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="name2" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[]" placeholder="desc2" /><br>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>
```

Как создать массив с названиями файлов которые были выбраны в первом или втором input. Имеется скрипт практически рабочий, но имеет дефект, что вместо названия файла имеется иероглиф

```
                    $this_is_it = array();
                    $post = array_values($_POST);
                            for($j = 0; $j < count($post[1]); $j++){
                                for($u = 0; $u < count($post[3]); $u++){
                                    $this_is_it['order_' . ($j + 1)] = array(
                                        'name'   => $post[1][$j],
                                        'desc'   => $post[2][$j],
                                        'attach' => $post[3][$j]
                                    );

                                }

                            }
```

Выводит он при этом:

```
array(2) { ["order_1"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(4) "lala" 
["desc"]=> string(7) "lalalal" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } 
                    ["order_2"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(5) "name2" 
["desc"]=> string(5) "desc2" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } }
```

Что делать как быть

Comment: Может быть просто повесить id для инпута? Типа value, или еще один hidden с айди заказа. Что-то в этом роде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="обработчик.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name1" />
    <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="desc1" />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />

    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name2" />
    <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="desc2" />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />

</form>
```

В этом случае обработчик получит массивы order и files, в которых данные с одинаковыми ключами будут содержать информацию об одном заказе. Вам остаётся их лепить вместе и обрабатывать по своему (в базу, письмом и т.д.)

```
обработчик.php

$this_is_it = array();
$post = array_values($_POST);

for($i = 0; $i < count($post[0]); $i++){

    for($j = 0; $j < count($post); $j++){

        $this_is_it['order_' . ($i + 1)] = array(
            'name'   => $post[0][$i],
            'desc'   => $post[1][$i],
            'attach' => $post[2][$i]
        );

    }

}
```

Получите массив $this_is_it, со сгруппированными данными заказов:

```
array (
  'order_1' => array (
      'name'   => 'name1',
      'desc'   => 'desc1',
      'attach' => 'картинка.jpg',
  ),
  'order_2' => array (
      'name'   => 'name2',
      'desc'   => 'desc2',
      'attach' => 'картинка_2.jpg',
  ),
```

)

Comment: Здравствуйте а можно с кусочком php кода чтобы показать как это работает а то я чтото не врубаюсь

Comment: Дополнил ответ по вашей просьбе.

Comment: Пробывал использовать сегодня вашу систему, все срабатывает прекрасно и делятся инпуты на работы, но если я добавляю файл то при отображении в var_dump(); у меня в поле attach появляется вот такой вот символ "�" может быть вопрос в кодировке или в чем то еще может быть проблема? И при добавлении нескольких файлов та же проблема могу приложить код загрузки файла если интересно.

Comment: покажите форму и вар_дапм. какие расширения файлов используются в аттаче и в какой кодировке?

Comment: Все отправлю ответом на свой вопрос

Comment: А какие имена и расширения файлов?

Comment: Ну к примеру copy_logo.png или пробовал еще .htaccess и торрент файлы, но изменение файлов не помогло

Comment: Проверил вашу схему без добавления файла поле, так же сама и получается, выводится непонятный символ

Comment: сабмитете аяксом?

Comment: нет вся обработка через php

Answer (score 0):

```
Var_dump: array(2) { ["order_1"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(4) "lala" 
["desc"]=> string(7) "lalalal" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } 
                    ["order_2"]=> array(3) { 
["name"]=> string(5) "name2" 
["desc"]=> string(5) "desc2" 
["attach"]=> string(1) "�" } }
```

Форма:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="addtask"></div>
            <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name1" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="desc1" /><br>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>

            <input type="text" name="name[]" value="name2" /><br>
            <input type="text" name="desc[]" value="desc2" /><br>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Нажми" name="enter"><br>
    </form>
```

Расширение файлов: пробовал разные расширения, основной .png и еще разные, обязательно нужны расширения .cdr, .pdf, .png, .jpeg

Кодировку файлов не нашел, но весь код переведен в UTF-8 через notepad++